# Math with jQuery /Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have dynamic input boxes with values of dates like this

```
<input size="30" id="date_one" value="21/03/2011" type="text">  

<input size="30" id="date_two" value="14/08/2010" type="text">
```

I want to calculate difference between these two dates. i.e. **How many days remaining ?**

Is it possible with jQuery to do this kind of math ? & How ?

**Thanks**

[DEMO : JQuery](http://www.jsfiddle.net/gXp6Y/)

[DEMO : Mootools](http://www.jsfiddle.net/pE5uS/1/)

Comment: Please do not tag this as Java - Javascript != Java. Also, jQuery isn't needed for this - it is a cross-browser library commonly used for DOM traversal, manipulation and ajax requests, not math.

Comment: With JQuery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at:

[Javascript Date difference as milliseconds, minutes, hours, days, weeks, months, or years](http://blog.stephenrushing.com/index.php/javascript/javascript-date-difference-as-milliseconds-minutes-hours-days-weeks-months-or-years/)

[See the demo here](http://blog.stephenrushing.com/wp-content/uploads/javascript/timeSpan/sample.html)